# Two object merge with two dates matching all records

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, object

How to merge two objects between two date range? I tried the following snippets but duplicate dates also to be update. But now its updating only matching values.

```
let dateRange =  [
  { Date: '2021-06-10' },
  { Date: '2021-06-11' },
  { Date: '2021-06-12' },
  { Date: '2021-06-13' },
  { Date: '2021-06-24' },
  { Date: '2021-06-25' },
  { Date: '2021-06-26' },
  { Date: '2021-06-27' }
]
let result = [
    {
      Type: 'Production',
      Date: '2021-06-26'
    },
    { Type: 'Production',
     Date: '2021-06-24'
    {
      Type: 'Production',
      Date: '2021-06-24'
    },
    {
      Type: 'Production',
      Date: '2021-06-25'
    },
    {
      Type: 'Production',
      Date: '2021-06-25'
    }
    ]
```

expected result:

```
[
  { Date: '2021-06-10' },
  { Date: '2021-06-11' },
  { Date: '2021-06-12' },
  { Date: '2021-06-13' },
    { Type: 'Production',
     Date: '2021-06-24'
    {
      Type: 'Production',
      Date: '2021-06-24'
    },
    {
      Type: 'Production',
      Date: '2021-06-25'
    },
    {
      Type: 'Production',
      Date: '2021-06-25'
    },
    {
      Type: 'Production',
      Date: '2021-06-26'
    },
    { Date: '2021-06-27' }
    ]
```

My approach:

```
let jsonObj = dateRange.map((range) => {
let result = result.find(({ Date }) => range.Date ==Date);
   return { ...range, ...result };
 });
```

But it returns only unique values.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following function with the `result` array you have generated.

```
const trueUnique = (arr) =>
      [...new Set(arr.map(JSON.stringify))]
      .map(res => JSON.parse(res))
```

Using the normal way of making a unique list (`[...new Set(arr)]`) didn't work since JavaScript only does shallow compares with the `Set()` constructor. But it can compare strings easily, so using `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse` you can use the `result` using your algorithm and make the results unique with `trueUnique()`

Edit:
This code will create the list correctly with duplicates

```
const withDuplicates = (range, result) => {
    const datesOnly = Object.fromEntries(result.map((obj, i) => [JSON.stringify(obj.Date), i]))
    const diffRange = range.reduce((acc, cur) => {
        if (!(JSON.stringify(cur.Date) in datesOnly)) return [...acc, {Date: cur['Date']}]
        else return acc
    }, [])
    return [...diffRange, result]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. But I need duplicate date values also. please have look once my expected outcome.

Answer (score 1):

```
let jsonObjMerged:any[] = [...result, ...dateRange]
   .reduce( (b:any[],a:any) => (a.Type || !b.some(e => e.Date === a.Date) ? [...b, a] : b),[])
   .sort((a:any,b:any) => new Date(a.Date).valueOf() - new Date(b.Date).valueOf());
```

Due to the Tyescript typing, this won't run in the snippet but you can test it [at TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=19&ssc=45&pln=18&pc=1#code/DYUwLgBAJghmICUYDsDmIBcKCeBtAuhALwS4BQA3gCJyYQDkATAAyMCMAtMwGwdvP0AvgBpKNeBgYt2XXmzZDR1WpKatOPPo0ViVU9bL4BmHcon6ZmxgBZT4umsu9GAVjt7HG593fnPhxgB2IXwyMlBIACcQAGcAV2AwLGQ8QhJyCEyICgAVbAAHBwAFSIB7KDiAYzAAS1LkemEIe1VpLw5GHxEyLOy8wtUS8qra+sbmjzaA227e3ILisorquoamlot2mx05-sXhlbH1yYMrN1ms+YGGIeXRtYm-KbOQgG4wiIgAKxj6gHkAEZfACyIEi6CgyVSxFIADp4dF4okmvDYbB4Eg0CB8LDossQAAKCAEgFQgjCGBQgCUxAAfMSYLC9hAAD4siAAQgBsN+AFtCSA6RAQLD7MQiCRGfYaQB+OHwgFNGCESQAqnCAhUnmlSJgAkEyk4YSknA0oj05AgADuj0JUtoWoAbjBgHEQH8AGYEmkcCCWm32Emih2w52u91eqlU96Veq-UCw4ClVAE+g-f5A0HgkCQxrp5CAkFgiHRoA)

```js
let dateRange:any[] = [
{Date: '2021-06-10'},
{Date: '2021-06-11'},
{Date: '2021-06-12'},
{Date: '2021-06-13'},
{Date: '2021-06-24'},
{Date: '2021-06-25'},
{Date: '2021-06-26'},
{ Date: '2021-06-27'}]

let result:any[] = [
    {Type: 'Production', Date: '2021-06-26'},
    {Type: 'Production', Date: '2021-06-24'},
    {Type: 'Production', Date: '2021-06-24'},
    {Type: 'Production', Date: '2021-06-25'},
    {Type: 'Production', Date: '2021-06-25'}]

//Typescript Version
let jsonObjMerged:any[] = [...result, ...dateRange].reduce( (b:any[],a:any) => (a.Type || !b.some(e => e.Date === a.Date) ? [...b, a] : b),[]).sort((a:any,b:any) => new Date(a.Date).valueOf() - new Date(b.Date).valueOf());
console.log('jsonObjMerged:',jsonObjMerged);
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. your code is returning unique values. That I have already getting in mycode. I want duplicate date values also. I hope you got it.

Comment: its not working in Typescript. I am getting following error:
The left-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number', 'bigint' or an enum type.

Comment: Thanks @Kinglish I added new Date(a.Date).valueOf() - new Date(b.Date).valueOf());   -> valueOf(). Its working. Thanks lot

Comment: great! I was trying to figure out how to have a <Date> assertion for TS on that line. `valueOf()` is perfect. The answer is updated and hope it helped solve your question.

Comment: Cool. Unless you're still waiting for other answers, please accept this one. Cheers!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233958/discussion-between-jay-and-kinglish).